# Change HSV of bitmap only specific region

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to change the HSV of bitmap I found out some help online but they are changing the HSV of whole image. In my case i have circular selector that enable user to select specific part of image and than change its HSV. It look like this

[image]

Can we do that without using any other third party image processing library?

Comment: Please elaborate your question and provide some code if possible. Explain **i have circular selector that enable user to select specific part of image**.

Comment: can you see the blue circle, this is a circular selector i was refering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to specifically get the pixel indices of the circle here is what you do:

```
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(X,Y);
float[] HSV=new float[3];
Color.RGBToHSV(Color.red(pixel), Color.green(pixel), Color.blue(pixel), HSV);
// Manipulate the HSV array as you want then,
bitmap.setPixel(X,Y, Color.HSVToColor(HSV));
```

PS: If you want to know how to get the X and Y coordinates of pixel please do comment. I'll edit the post as per your requirements.

**EDIT :**

Here is how you get pixels of the circular area (and manipulate it) provided you have the co-ordinate of the center of the circle and the radius of the circle you want the manipulation to.

```
int centerX = 100; // This is the X co-ordinate of the center of your circle
int centerY = 100; // This is the Y co-ordinate of the center of your circle
int radius = 40; // This is the radius of the circle you want
for(int Y=centerY-radius; Y<=centerY+radius;Y++)
{
    for(int X=centerX-radius;X<=centerX+radius;X++)
    {
        int distance = (int)Math.sqrt(Math.pow((X-centerX),2) + Math.pow((Y-centerY),2));
        if(distance<=radius)
        {
            int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(X,Y);
            float[] HSV=new float[3];
            Color.RGBToHSV(Color.red(pixel), Color.green(pixel), Color.blue(pixel), HSV);
            // Manipulate the HSV array as you want then,
            bitmap.setPixel(X,Y, Color.HSVToColor(Color.alpha(pixel),HSV));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i am not able to get circular pixel. The method getpixel() of bitmap has no such arugment that can help me to get circular region pixels

Comment: @umerk44 I have edited my answer to suit your comment. Use the above method to perform the task.

Comment: your code gives me an error illegalstateexception at bitmap.setPixel(). Any idea?

Comment: i got it, bitmap should be muteable

Comment: why it's changing detail of image, it displayed solid color like ink spot:). i don't want to change detail of image

Comment: Please update your question and add code. Then I'll be able to understand and answer what you want to achieve.

Comment: i really appreciate your help so far what i really want is to change the hue of image the code you provided me changes the color of desired region but it just ruined the detail of image. it changes it's color into solid opaque color which destroy image detail. For better understanding consider example of changing hair color, changing eye color. hope you understand my point

Comment: still the same problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54673/discussion-between-abdul-fatir-and-umerk44).

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use [Bitmap.setPixel(int, int, int);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixel%28int,%20int,%20int%29) , to change the color at position(x, y).

or

1. you can create a canvas use from a bitmap use

   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

and you can add new content on the original bitmap.